# How to Select Date Time with Month and Year Only .Net

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I want to make user select date time month and year only. Even though i added bootstrap's datepicker i couldnt success.

Here is my java script code in another file.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#datepicker").datepicker(
    {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        format: "mm/yyyy",
        language: "tr"
    });
```

});

And my html and css codes down the below.

```
<form method="post" asp-action="Create">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row p-2">
        <h2 class="text-primary row-6">Create a Period</h2>
    </div>

    @*<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>*@
    <div class="my-3">
        <label asp-for="Period"></label>
        <input asp-for="Period" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="my-3">
        <label asp-for="PardiemType"></label>
        <input asp-for="PardiemType" class="form-control" id="datepicker" />
    </div>                

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
    <a asp-controller="UserPeriod" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-secondary">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

```
@section Scripts{
@{
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
    <script src="~/js/period.js"></script>
}
```

}

At the end i get an output like this. As you can see user can select day, month and year. Which point am i missing?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my current **1.9.0** version of `bootstrap-datepicker`. You could set `startView` and `minViewMode` like below to achieve your requirement:

```
<div class='input-group date datepicker' id='datepicker'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
@section Scripts
{    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />   
    <script>
        $(function () {           
            $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                format: 'mm/yyyy',              
                startView: "months",
                minViewMode: "months",
                language: "tr"
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Before version `1.2.0`, you may set `viewMode` and `minViewMode`.

Comment: How do you know that i could set viewMode and minViewMode before 1.2.0. Is there a documentation?

Comment: Hi @omneer, check [this document](https://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)